# Enforcing case insensitive column references in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am working with SQL Server 2014. I have dynamically generated SQL which looks like this (simplified for brevity):

```
with CTE as 
(
    select field as [field], field as [Field] 
    from myTable
)
select [field], [Field] 
from CTE
```

The above however results in this error:

> The column 'Field' was specified multiple times for 'CTE'.

I would expect/want this to work because the 2 columns are in fact unique, accounting for case. Is there anyway we can ask SQL (via some SET option maybe) to treat them as unique?

My dynamically generated SQL is very complex and it's very difficult to identify such 'duplicates' and 'combine' them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a theoretical perspective, you *could* change the collation of your database to a case-sensitive option.  Case-sensitive database/server collations will also consider the case sensitivity of aliases.  Table column collations, and collating a column in a select will not.

[Changing database/server collation will change a whole lot else though](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/questions-sql-server-collations-shy-ask/).  It would be a very extreme change to fix an alias issue and I doubt it is a viable solution for you.

That said, if your dynamic SQL is able to see that the alias `field` already exists and use the capitalized alias `Field` for the next instance of the same column, I would think you could simply adjust that to be `field1`, `field2` etc.  You can always re-alias those to whatever you want in your outer/final select, they just need to be unique in the CTE query.

Comment: Thanks. I also see that there is a COLLATE clause I can use in the SELECT statement, should I try using that here, without affecting the overall database?

Comment: @cooper_milton Unfortunately that won't work either.  Only the database or server collation will consider the case-sensitivity of aliases.